# Just beginning to learn piano, need some help

Tags: piano, sheet-music, beginner

Hello I'm beginning to learn piano this year and my biggest obstacle is reading piano sheets.

Can someone give some tips on how to improve my sheet reading or any general tips on piano? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's a very wide question!   I'll just offer you two things.  Trust your teacher.  Do what she says, even if you can't see the point in it.  And learn to read by reading LOTS.  The top line in the hymnbook will do.  But read something new every day.

Have fun!

Comment: I agree with you. Though I have met teachers who I guess were talented from young. They could not teach reading to save their lives. One used to say ‘read it!’ And when I asked how she should say ‘by reading it!’ I didn’t get very far. I recommend the Paul Harris improve your sight reading books for their impeccable progression.

Answer (score 3):

as OP said, that's a very vague question, it depends what you're looking to achieve in the long term, I recommend these:

1. Look into Theory. It would definitely help to be at about RCM Basic Rudiments AKA Level 5 Theory/ABRSM Level 5 theory as this will be important at higher level piano.
2. Find songs that you know (eg movie/video game theme, holiday song, song from hymn book) and play them. You'll feel a lot more motivated to keep trying if a part is giving you a hard time than something unfamiliar. (Obviously if you're just starting out, don't pick a very complicated arrangement which will take you a long time to learn).
3. Try [Sight Reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sight-reading) sheets of music, your sight reading skills will obviously improve and by seeing different notation (eg sforzando, mordent etc), it is a learning opportunity as you'll see the application of the theory
4. Experiment with things, regardless if you want to be a jazz pianist or going for baroque repertoire. It can be fun and once you know more of the theory, piano improvisation can become much more interesting (I don't really improvise much but know people who have greatly benefited from doing so)

Again, this is what I recommend but you can easily find lists online of tips for beginner pianists.

Good luck and Have Fun :)

Comment: hi what does aka stands for?

Comment: @LoveIsHere "Also Known As"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what it's already said, I think it's a good idea to sing ​​what you're playing. While you practice, sing or hum the melody, you do not need to be in tune or trying to do it perfectly. Simply, singing helps to concentrate. Hands can go on their own, but if you sing you force yourself to concentrate, to focus on what you are doing and what is written.